# Curly like mushroom in my greenhouse are they harmful

Tags: mushrooms

Curly like mushroom in my greenhouse are they harmful? What caused them? How do I get rid of them?

Comment: Fungus loves moisture. Picture would help.

Comment: Also new dirt may have a lot of wood components: good to keep moisture (so good for seeds and seedlings), and with *nutrients*. Mushrooms may just help on preparing further the soil. In general: they are good if they do not growth from your vegetables (and such fungi/mushrooms are very tiny, you just see them as powder or dots). So we need a photo, not to overgeneralize.